# Google Sheets - Count Row if Values in Adjoining Cells Match Two Strings AND Another Value Pair is not Present in the same Row

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

Similar to my [previous SO article][1], I want to count a row if two adjoining cells contain specified strings. If the row contains another specified pair of strings then I don't want to count the row regardless if it meets the first criteria.

Here's an example... in the below table, I first want to check col1, col4, and col7 if any of the cells contain string1. If any of them do, I want to check the cell immediately adjacent to it, to see if it contains string 2. If it does then it counts as 1...

...unless in the same row either col1, col4, and col7 also contain string1, but the adjacent cell contains string3.

Additionally if there are multiple instances of string1 and string2 in the correct cells, its still only counts as 1.

string1 = "a"

string2 = "b"

string3 = "c"

```
      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9
row1  "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "e"   "x"   "y"   "z"   "o" 
row2  "c"   "d"   "a"   "b"   "a"   "c"   "z"   "o"   "y"
row3  "a"   "y"   "a"   "a"   "b"   "o"   "a"   "c"   "x"   
row4  "a"   "b"   "x"   "d"   "e"   "z"   "a"   "b"   "c"
```

So with this example table I would want a final result of 2 as row1 has string1 in col1 and, and col2 has string2 in it. Row 4 has string1 and string2 in the right columns twice, but still only counts once. Row 2 doesn't count because string1 and string2 are in the wrong columns. Row 3 doesn't count because despite string1 and string2 being in the right columns, there is also a pairing of string1 and string3 in the right cells.

EDIT
Here is the link to the [actual spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16-nHzCwlCasM6KMTuizsWoPwmER7BrjyHH0B99sXObM/edit?usp=sharing). If you look at the 'results' sheet, E7 cell. The formula should return 0 in this case, as there are two times when 'Firey War Axe' is "dumped" but also kept. See row 44 and row 56 in the 'data' sheet for the examples. These two rows should not be counted.

Comment: For `row3` the negated adjacent strings **a** & **c** are in col8, col9. The columns do not match with the allotted col1, col4, and col7. Is that intended and row3 still be disregarded?!

Comment: @rockinfreakshow I have adjusted my example. In row 3 "a" was meant to be in col7, and "c" in col8. And yes, row three is meant to be disregarded

Answer (score 1):

***Updated answer***:

```
=countif(byrow(choosecols(index(ifs((Data!E:N=A7)*(Data!F:O="Dumped"),A7,(Data!E:N=A7)*(Data!F:O="Kept"),"Dumped",1,)),1,4,7,10),lambda(Σ,
               ifna(xmatch(A7,Σ)^0)+let(Λ,ifna(xmatch("Dumped",Σ)),if(Λ=0,,max(2,Λ))))),1)
```

Comment: I can't get this to work with the actual spreadsheet I am using. Maybe its just easier to share a link to it.

Comment: I've edited the OP with a link to the spreadsheet and more detail

Comment: Do test out the updated answer.